# moving breadcrumb to right below the text and next to image, but won't just move

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble moving breadcrumb to below my text.

I'm trying to move breadcrumb to right below the text. I did `padding-left`, `float:left`, but they won't just fit right. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for breadcrumb:

```
<ol class="post-info">
   <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{ post.pub_date | date }}<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{post.views}}<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{ post.moderator.username }}<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
      <a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-default">discuss</a>
      <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-default">{{post.category}}<i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></a>
   </div>
</ol>
```

And this is the `css` for my breadcrumb, but they can be changed. Can change size or anything that bothers from moving.

```
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ebebeb;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #adadad;
}
```

Here is my `html` code, I'm trying to fit breadcrumb

```
<td class="vert-align">
  {% if post.url %}
     <h4 id="line">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" style="margin-left: 15px;"> 
           <img src="{{post.image}}" height="85" width="85"/> 
           <span id="title-font">{{ post.title }}</span>
        </a>
        <span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">
           ({{ post.domain }})
        </span>
      </h4>
  {% else %}
      <h4>
         <a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" style="margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ post.title }}
         </a>
         <span style="margin-left: 15px; "class="domain">
            ({{ post.domain }})
         </span>
       </h4>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

And below this code the breadcrumb code goes in. Then I get the picture like I posted on imgur.

Comment: Opps I forgot to add css file for the html cell, it's just table.thread td {
 padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px ;
}

Comment: Mr Jay do you know the answer?

Comment: Can you add a snippet with the output code (Not server side code) so we could see the problem in live? It will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I figured it out thank you very much

Comment: I don't feel comfortable leaving the image like that